# Swift Unit Test function that async dispatches a block that sets a variable I want to test

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have some code that is like the following

```
class Vibration: NSObject {
    var status: VibrationStatus // an enum
}
```

and a function on another class (of type NSObject) like the following, that is part of an object that has a property vibration of type Vibration

```
func vibrate() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
       vibration.status = .vibrating
       // do some real HW vibrate stuff
    }
}
```

None of the properties or class definitions include `@objc` or `@objcMembers`

I am trying to create a test that will wait for that async call to set the vibration.status.

I have a test function that seems to work (see below) when I declare the `status` property as `@objc` or put `@objcMembers` on the `Vibration` class.

```
func testVibrate() {
    let invite: SignalingInviteBody = SignalingInviteBody()
    let incomingCall = IncomingCall(invite)
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "status = 2"), object: incomingCall.vibration)
    incomingCall.startRing() // this calls the function vibrate()
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 3.0)
}
```

This test also requires `@objc` on the enum declaration with Objective-C compatible enum declaration, which I don't want as it would only be for testing.

Except for testing, there is no need to make the `status` property `@objc` or the `Vibration` class as `@objcMembers` and I would rather not change the base program code to a more inefficient style when I don't need the Objective-C compatibility in the base program.

Is there a way to unit test this in a real, honest to goodness, Swift way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: this is just some pseudo-code I nailed out quickly in the browser. It'll probably need some polishing before it compiles properly.

I would use a mock and dependency injection:

```
class MockVibration: Vibration {
    let statusChanged: (VibrationStatus) -> Void

    init(statusChanged: (VibrationStatus) -> Void) {
        self.statusChanged = statusChanged
    }

    var status: VibrationStatus {
        didSet {
            statusChanged(status)
        }
    }
}
```

I would probably have a protocol, and have `Vibration` and `MockVibration` both conform to it, but having `MockVibration: Vibration` should work well. Once you've defined this mock, you can use it to fulfill an expectation in your test case:

```
func testVibrate() {
    let didVibrate = self.expectation(description: "Started vibrating")
    let mockVibration = MockVibration { newStatus in 
        XCTAssertEqual(newStatus, .vibrating)
        didVibrate.fulfill()
    }

    let invite = SignalingInviteBody()
    let incomingCall = IncomingCall(invite, mockVibration)
    

    incomingCall.startRing() // this calls the function vibrate()

    wait(for: [didVibrate], timeout: 3.0)
}
```

---

You might even be able to rework this interface so that `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` happens within the `Vibration` class as an internal detail. If you do that, the interaction between `IncomingCall` and `Vibration` becomes synchronous, so you wouldn't need to use expectations. Your incoming call test would reduce to:

```
class MockVibration {
    // The mock can just have its status set simply/synchronously
    var status: VibrationStatus = .off // or some other "initial" value
}

func testVibrate() {
    let mockVibration = MockVibration()

    let invite = SignalingInviteBody()
    let incomingCall = IncomingCall(invite, mockVibration)
    

    incomingCall.startRing() // this calls the function vibrate()

    XCTAssertEqual(mockVibration.status, .vibrating)
}
```

Of course, then you'd need a separate test that covers `Vibration`, and ensures that its public APIs cause it to change its internal state using the right dispatch queue or whatever.